# Encode raw PCM to AAC using OSX native library

Tags: macos, signal-processing, core-audio, audio-processing

I wonder if there is a way to **encode raw data to aac format using OSX native libraries**? If yes, are there some examples or documentation?

I looked up the apple documentation but only found decoding related resources using Core Audio framework.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569015/writing-buffer-of-audio-samples-to-aac-file-using-extaudiofilewrite-for-ios) is what I wanted!

Comment: Checkout previous answers like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271186/how-do-i-use-coreaudios-audioconverter-to-encode-aac-in-real-time and the Apple example, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/iPhoneACFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for the resources! I will check and write a comment about which one fit me.